# How to compare a.value & b.value if they has the same type?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I fetched "a" object by KVC.  (don't know the exact class of "a")
Then I fetched "b" by KVC too (don't know the exact class of "b" either)

I want to compare a.value with b.value. 
if those "value" is the same type (NSString / NSDate / NSNumber)

How to accomplish these task?

Comment: How do you know both have a `.value`?

Comment: Please add the used language to the tags.

Comment: I just iterated through list of multiple type of NSManagedobject . Then compare them to  [anyJsonDic allkeys] .   Then matched them  by "key" . vs "key".    This key should have the same @"name" so i so could transfer the value from a . to . b .              Problem is , though i know they have the same name i cant guarantee (is the CoreData Entity  setting value type correctly ??) .     thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([a isEqual:b]) {
    // the same type and value
} else {
    // different type or value
}
```

Comment: problem is  NSMObj didnt have any value yet .   i just want to compare "type" of the variables .    if (NSMObj.unknowVar    isSameTypeAs    b.unknownVar) ...

Comment: @Memexeiei To compare classes you can use: if ([a isMemberOfClass:[b class]]) {}.

Comment: some . .unknowVar is primitive variables . how to compare them .. thanks

Comment: @Memexeiei AFAIK, in KVC primitive values are implicitly wrapped in object classes like NSNumber.